# How can I send email via microsoft-graph using my application?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/sendMail

What does the {id} refers to?

Comment: I found this helpful article https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-my-user-id-and-why-do-i-need-it-e456eb4c-9cb9-4aa0-9d0a-923b8c53228d

Answer (score 0):

The id refers either to the email address or to the id of the user you want to send the email from. You can also replace /users/{id} by /me which is a shortcut to the current user.